# Combine GroupBy Object and DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe and a groupby object that I want to add as columns to the groupby. They are the right shape to fit together, but for some reason don't.
I've tried using concat and merge to no avail.
df is type <class 'pandas.core.groupby.generic.DataFrameGroupBy'>
months_since_df is type <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

```
df_fin = pd.concat([df, months_since_df], axis=1, join="inner")
```

```
df_fin = pd.merge(df, months_since, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

When I do this I keep getting the following error.

```
TypeError: Can only merge Series or DataFrame objects, a <class 'pandas.core.groupby.generic.DataFrameGroupBy'> was passed"
```

Ultimately my goal is to add months_since_df column to df.
This is the first time I'm using groupby, is there something basic I'm missing (sure feels like it.)
happy to clarify and add additional info if needed. Thanks!

Comment: what is the output of `type(df)` and `type(months_since_df)`?

Comment: type(df) <class 'pandas.core.groupby.generic.DataFrameGroupBy'>
type(months_since_df) <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

Comment: How did you generate `df`? you can't use a `DataFrameGroupBy` in a concat/merge

Comment: it is the original data. df is the grouped dataframe passed into the function (probably should change the name). 
How would I add columns to the DataFrameGroupBy?

Comment: Why don't you just **not groupby** in the first place? ;)

Comment: Hahaha, I need to segment my data and apply a bunch of stuff to those segments. Groupby seemed like the best way to do that

Comment: well if you `groupby` you need to aggregate or transform at some point. here you did the first step not the second, so either do both or none ;)

Comment: You should step back a bit and explain what you wanted to do in the first place

Comment: I want to transform the data, but don't want to lose the integrity of the column. So I have a group with many dates in it. I want to take the first date (already sorted) and see how many months are between the months. 
Data should look something like this
Date, Months Since
01-01-2021, 0
01-02-2021, 1